# How to push Viewcontroller from rootViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 ViewController. loginViewControl which sets to rootViewControoler :

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    loginViewControl = [[LoginTab alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = loginViewControl;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

And I create StatusViewController :
*.h

```
 @interface StatusViewController : UIViewController<UITabBarControllerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;

    IBOutlet UIButton *UploadButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *ConvertorButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *CompletedButton;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
@end
```

Now I want to push StatusViewController from loginViewControl(rootviewcontroller).I used below code but it not work.

```
 - (IBAction)statusButtonClick:(id)sender;
{
    StatusViewController *statusView = [[StatusViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:statusView animated:YES];

    [statusView release];   

}
```

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not setting UINavigationViewcontroller at the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of Window's RootViewcontroller, We can't Push a `UIViewController` without `UINavigationViewcontroller`

So First Set LoginViewController as a RootViewController of `UINavigationViewcontroller` like Bellow:-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    loginViewControl = [[YourLoinViewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourLoinViewcontroller" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *objNavigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginViewControl];

    self.window.rootViewController = objNavigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

**EDIT**

Connect your `StatusViewcontroller's` view with File owner like bellow:-

[image]

your push method like this:-

```
- (IBAction)statusButtonClick:(id)sender;
{
    StatusViewController *statusView = [[StatusViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"StatusViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:statusView animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: I tried your code but it show error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "StatusViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
"

Comment: at that your xib you not connect view with fileOwner this error bcz of you not connect StatusViewController's View with FileOwner

Comment: StatusViewController has a tabbarController

Comment: Thanks, I connected view to FileOwner,i works but it can't show Tabbarcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Unless your login view controller is a navigation controller, self.navigationController in statusButtonClick will return nil and so this won't work.
Maybe you can try:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    loginViewControl = [[LoginTab alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewControl];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

This will enclose a loginViewController in a navigationController which will permit you to push another viewController in the navigationController's stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)statusButtonClick:(id)sender; {

    // If used StoryBoard
    UIStoryboard *story=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    StatusViewController *statusView = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StatusViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:statusView animated:YES];

    // If used XIB
     StatusViewController *statusView = [[StatusViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"StatusViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:statusView animated:YES]; }
```